# How to update magento 2.3.0 to 2.3.1?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php-7

Magento just released new versions of Magento Commerce and Open Source to increase product security, performance, and functionality.
One of it is the **Magento Commerce and Open Source 2.3.1.**

My question is, **how to update Magento  2.3.0 to the latest version 2.3.1?**

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can upgrade via admin as well,
To run System Upgrade:

1. Log in to the Magento Admin as an administrator.
2. Click System > Tools > Web Setup Wizard. The following page displays.
3. Click System Configuration.

For more details visit [upgrade via admin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/upgrader/upgrade-start.html)

CLI upgrade :

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/
rm -rf var/page_cache/
rm -rf var/generation/
chmod +x bin/magento
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

For more details about CLI upgrade visit [Upgrade via CLI](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html)

These are the steps enough to upgrade via CLI as far as I've read through.

Always remember to make a backup!

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it's done after update 2.3.1 payment checkout page "the shiiping method is missing.select the shipping method try again" how to solve?

Comment: I get this error trying that.

 [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find a matching version of package magento/product-community-edition. Check the package spelling, your ve
  rsion constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (stable).

Answer (score 8):

Upgrade Magento version 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 follow below steps:

Magento 2 Version Upgrade Commands.

1) `php bin/magento maintenance:enable`

2) `composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 --no-update`

3) `composer update`

4) `rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/*`

5) `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

6) `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

7) `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

8) `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

9) `php bin/magento cache:clean`

10) `php bin/magento cache:flush`

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

11) `php bin/magento --version`

12) `php bin/magento maintenance:disable`

Done.

Comment: Getting this error:   Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.3.0, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.1.0, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.1, 2.0.10, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.0.11, 2.1.4, 2.0.12, 2.1.5, 2.0.13, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.0.14, 2.0.15, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.0.16, 2.2.0, 2.0.17, 2.2.1, 2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.2.2, 2.0.18, 2.1.12, 2.2.3, 2.1.13, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.2.6, 2.1.16, 2.2.7] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You can update to 2.3.1 Open Source via the System Upgrade in admin panel

System -> Tools -> Web Setup Wizard -> System Upgrade.

!!Remember to always backup!!