# Magento 2 Cloud version upgrade issue

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2-cloud, magento2.2.9

I am upgrading Magento version 2.2.7 to 2.2.9
I used the following commands on local setup

```
$ composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":"2.2.9" --no-update

$ composer update
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/magento-cloud-metapackage (locked at 2.2.7, required as 2.2.9) is satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.2.7] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  

Problem 2
    - Can only install one of: magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.9, 2.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.9, 2.2.7].
    - Can only install one of: magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7, 2.2.9].
    - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.9 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.2.9 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.9].

    - Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.2.9 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.2.9].

    - Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition (locked at 2.2.7) -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.2.7].
```

please provide solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267753/how-to-update-magento-2-3-0-to-2-3-1/267760#267760

Comment: I followed following guide
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html
 and my magento installation is not community-edition

Comment: show your composer.json file

Answer (score 2):

#### Understanding Package Management

First off, any answers that suggest removing or editing the `composer.lock` file directly are **wrong**. Deleting `composer.lock` and regenerating will effectively upgrade every package to the latest version as specified by your `composer.json` file, and you should **never** edit the lock file directly.

`magento/magento-cloud-metapackage` is, as its name suggests, a meta-package - AKA a package that represents a collection of other packages that go together, as opposed to a module of code. In this case, the main dependency (or sub/child-package) here is `magento/product-enterprise-edition` which has been locked to an older version per your `composer.lock`.

#### Understanding Your Error

Assuming you don't have both the cloud *and* enterprise packages in your `composer.json`, what you need to tell Composer is that you want to upgrade `magento/magento-cloud-metapackage` *and* any of its sub-packages or **dependencies**. Conveniently enough, `composer update` has a flag you can use for this.

What you want to run is the below:

```bash
$ composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":"2.2.9" --no-update
$ composer update --with-dependencies
```

or more concisely...

```bash
$ composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":"2.2.9" --update-with-dependencies
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `composer.lock` file present on the root on your local installation.

The issue is that your Magento version specified in the `composer.lock` file is 2.2.7 but you are upgrading to 2.2.9.

You can fix this problem by manually changing the version in the `composer.lock` file or replace it with the production's `composer.lock` file.

After that, run the below commands to upgrade Magento to 2.2.9.

```
rm -rf var/ generated/
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope it helps you to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `composer.json` file and see if `magento/product-enterprise-edition` is included in it.  If so, remove it and try again.

If that does not resolve the issue, you could also delete your `composer.lock` file and `vendor` folders locally and run `composer update`.