# How to upgrade a Magento Cloud project via Composer?

Tags: magento2, composer, magento-cloud

In a Magento Enterprise or Magento Community version I just need to change the package version in my `composer.json`.

[image: Magento 2 Enterprise update via Composer]

How could I do the same in my Magento 2.3.7-p1 Cloud to update to Magento 2.3.7-p2?

[image: Magento 2 Cloud metapackage]

Answer (score 1):

### Metapackage

As you in [this other answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/314882/16416), `magento/magento-cloud-metapackage` is, as its name suggests, a meta-package - AKA a package that represents a collection of other packages that go together, as opposed to a module of code. In this case, the main dependency (or sub/child-package) here is `magento/product-enterprise-edition` which has been locked to an older version per your `composer.lock`.

### How to upgrade

You just need to update your Magento Cloud Metapackage with its dependencies.

```
composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage --with-dependencies
```

You will see this message below.

[image: Magento 2 Cloud upgrade]

Running this command below you will see the availability of the child enterprise package versions and its current version too.

```
composer show magento/product-enterprise-edition --all
```

[image: Magento Composer package versions]