# How to upgrade Magento Enterprise Edition?

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2-enterprise, magento2.4.0

I am a newbie for the Magento enterprise edition. I am upgrading Magento 2.3.5-p2 to Magento 2.4.0 in Enterprise Edition.

Following commands used with MySQL 5.7 and php7.3:

```
 composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
 composer update
```

During 'composer update' getting an error from the Magento module.

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried with included Magento keys in the auth.json file. But it's not worked. Did I add keys from the purchased account will it work? or any other solution for this error.

The "http://xxrepo.xxx.com/dist/magento/module-ui/magento-module-ui-101.2.0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)

Please let me know if anyone knows how to resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/352199/how-to-upgrade-a-magento-cloud-project-via-composer/352200#352200

Comment: Can you please try once by using the keys in Magento enterprise edition (from the account purchase was made) and pasting the same in auth.json, this generally happens when either the enterprise license is not activated or blocked due to license fees.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to run  `composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update`

you can use below method to upgrade the commerce edition, for eg if you want to upgrade to 2.4.3 then below command will be used.

```
composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=2.4.3 <2.4.4" --no-update -vvv
composer update magento/magento-cloud-metapackage -vvv
composer update -vvv
```

After this, you need to commit your changed files and merge them with integration or staging instances.

more detailed information you can find [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html)

Comment: I found this command in Magento official website.  composer require-commerce magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.0 --no-update
https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the Magento commerce cloud has different steps than the open-source version.

Following are some quick steps.

```
Step 1: composer require "magento/magento-cloud-metapackage":">=CURRENT_VERSION <NEXT_VERSION" --no-update

Step 2: composer update

Step 3: commit and push that changes to cloud.
```

This is only the primary step, but you have to do many configuration changes, ece-tool upgrades, and other server changes. Here are the detailed steps. You can view details steps here https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-upgrade.html

**NOTE**: If you upgrade from the too old version of Magento to the latest one (like 2.2 to 2.4), then you have to do database table changes.
Because you might be using the old version of DB in the old Magento and the latest Magento version, the newest version of the MariaDB is used.

Following is the details steps for that.
https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052191791-Upgrade-MariaDB-10-0-to-10-2-for-Magento-Commerce-Cloud-

Comment: This is not giving correct result what i want. Its upgrading cloud meta package. I want to upgrade magento/product-enterprise-edition